# Two curious series for $1/\pi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, combinatorial-identities, congruences, ramanujan

On Jan. 18, 2012 I conjectured that for any prime $p>3$ we have
$$R_p^2\equiv\frac1{10}\left(512\left(\frac{10}p\right)-27\left(\frac{-15}p\right)-475\right)\pmod p,$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}p)$ denotes the Legendre symbol and
$$R_p:=\frac1p\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\frac{6n+1}{(-1728)^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k(-324)^{n-k}.$$
Motivated by this I believed in 2011 that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{6n+1}{(-1728)^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k(-324)^{n-k}=\frac{c}{\pi}$$
for some algebraic number $c$, but I could not figure out the exact value of $c$ at that time.

On August 19, 2020 I learned from Dr. Deyi Chen that Maple has a function to justify the form of an algebraic number if we know enough digits of this number. Inspired by this, here I pose the following conjecture.

**Conjecture 1.** We have
$$\begin{aligned}&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{6n+1}{(-1728)^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k(-324)^{n-k}\\&\qquad=\frac{24}{25\pi}\sqrt{375+120\sqrt{10}}.
\end{aligned}\tag{1}$$

On June 16, 2011 I conjectured that for any odd prime $p\not=5$ we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}\frac{4n+1}{(-160)^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k(-20)^{n-k}\equiv 0\pmod p.$$
Motivated by this I formulated the following conjecture on August 20, 2020.

**Conjecture 2.** We have
$$\begin{aligned}&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4n+1}{(-160)^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k(-20)^{n-k}\\&\qquad=\frac{\sqrt{30}}{5\pi}\cdot\frac{5+\root 3\of{145+30\sqrt6}}{\root 6\of{145+30\sqrt6}}.
\end{aligned}\tag{2}$$

I have checked $(1)$ and $(2)$ for the first $100$ decimal digits.

**Question**. How to prove the identities $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Note that my two other similar conjectural identities
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{357n+103}{2160^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k(-324)^{n-k}=\frac{90}{\pi}\tag{3}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{3645^n}\binom{2n}n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k486^{n-k}=\frac{10}{3\pi}\tag{4}$$
found in 2011-2012 and published in [this paper](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/%7Ezwsun/157b.pdf) also remain open.

Comment: What is the relation between the congruence and the identity for pi? Is there an explanation for why we would expect such things?

Comment: You may look at my talk available from http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/CNT-talk3.pdf and my recent paper available from http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.3934/era.2020070.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting!